# USBメモリからApacheの起動

Tags: windows, apache

USBメモリにApacheを入れて起動させたいのですが、ドライブが変わると起動しません。
conf以下の設定ファイルはドライブが変わると正しくドライブ名は変更しています。

他に設定を変更するファイルがあるのでしょうか？
何が悪いのかわかる方がいれば教えて下さい。

※ PCのOSはWindows 8とWindows 7を交互に切り替えています。

---

自己解決しました。
お騒がせいたしました。

Comment: 何が問題だったのか、またそれをどのように解決したのか追記していただくと、後で読む人のためになります。是非書かれてはいかがでしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

/conf下のファイルを設定すれば、問題なく動作します。
.NETFRAMEWORKはWindows 7は3.5迄ですから、4.xにしますと動作しません。
そういう事でした。